# App drawer doesn't allow scrolling by letter on Android M Dev Preview 3

Tags: app-drawer, 6.0-marshmallow, developer-preview

I just flashed the newest Dev Preview of Marshmallow, but I found the App Drawer looks different than most screenshots.

Mine:

[image: IMG: no section on the left]

Screenshots:

[image: IMG: section divider on the left]

Is there a setting I need to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing the older Dev Preview 1 to the newer Dev Preview app drawer.

From [an article on AndroidPit](https://www.androidpit.com/android-m-release-date-news-features-name),

> **App drawer has been fixed**
>
> While we commend Google on trying a new, vertical-scrolling app drawer, the alphabetical dividers on the left and negative space at the end of some sections was a bad idea. The new Android M removes these and is faster to navigate because you have more app icons on screen. It still scrolls vertically though.
>
> [image: old & new app drawer]
>
> <sup>The old app drawer (left) and the new Android M developer preview 2 app drawer (right). / © ANDROIDPIT</sup>

AFAIK, there's no official way to revert back to the older version, unless you are OK with flashing Dev Preview 1 (and stuck with it).

Alternatively (though I haven't tried it, **so do it at your own risk**), based on [another article on AndroidPit](https://www.androidpit.com/get-android-m-s-new-app-drawer-on-lollipop-right-now), try to replace Google App with older version, specifically the Android M Preview 1.

> **Install the new APK app for Android Marshmallow**
>
> Once you've installed Google Now Launcher (OP: already installed by default on Nexus), you need to download the Google App APK file. To do this:
>
> - Make sure your device is set to accept downloads from unknown sources. To enable this, go to **Settings > Security** then tick the **Unknown sources** box.
> - Next, download the Google App APK file to your device, which you can get directly by [clicking here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/wi777bv1h1172xa/Velvet-Google-Search.apk). Open the APK once you've downloaded it, then follow the instructions to install Google App.

**Note**: you probably need to uninstall Google App's update first. Also, by installing from unknown source, Google App can't receive automatic update from Play Store anymore.

Comment: That's a good answer, thank you! I didn't know you could scroll by letter in the new one, that's what I need!